# How to restore updatingLocation after restart iPhone?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I make iBeacon-based application. I want to reach better proximity than gives major-minor, I want to use ranging. Problem, that it doesn't work more then 10 seconds in background. Ok, I use startUpdatingLocation and ranging works fine ... until device is rebooted. After reboot, ranging doesn't work. I think it because of startUpdatingLocation doesn't perform in background and after rebooting application doesn't become foreground. Have anybody solve the same problem, how to start ranging after rebooting device?

Answer (score 0):

Only monitoring can launch an app into the background based on a beacon detection.  To do what you want, you have to both monitor for beacons and range for beacons at the same time.  The monitoring `didEnterRegion` callback will trigger a background launch of your app, and then ranging will start automatically if you have it set up.

```
locationManager.startMontoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
```

You can also extend ranging beyond 10 seconds for up to 3 minutes, as described in my [blog post here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html)

Comment: Yes, but not 10 seconds nor 3 minutes is not enough for my project :(

Comment: Sorry, that's the best you can do without requesting special background permissions or playing tricks with region entry/exit events.  See details in the linked blog post.